# (CSS-Javascript-Jquery) How to make thumbnails slider for a carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm trying to make a carousel with thumbnails navigation. Something like  [this Carousel](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-slider-2.slider)
Due to I don't know how much thumbnails there will be, it should be something like a slider, with previous and next buttons.
I tried with an unordered list but only the first li is shown. What is wrong with this code?

Here is my code:

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel img.main
.previous {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.previous:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.next:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.thumbnavigator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: purple;
}
.thumbnavigator:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.thumbnavigator img {
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <img class="main" src="http://www.car-magazine.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Ferrari-Sergio3_4antSX.jpg" />

  <div class="previous">
  </div>

  <div class="next">
  </div>

  <div class="thumbnavigator">
    <!-- Thumbnails list slider -->
      <ul>
  <li>
    <img src = "http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src = "http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src = "http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src = "http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src = "http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src = "http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the JavaScript/jQuery portion of your code; where did you get stuck, what went wrong?

Comment: Help in making it? You haven't even got a starting point other than some html and css. This isn't a mentoring service or code writing service. Once you have some real code and have problems you will get lots of help

Comment: Sorry guys, I forget about copying the UL in the code, and for now I have no javascript. I tried with UL but just the first thumbnail was shown. Now I added the UL to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the following CSS rule:

```
.carousel img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This will affect both the main image and each thumbnail, resulting in all thumbnails being stacked on top of each other, because of `position:absolute`.

Simply changing the selector from `.carousel img` to `.carousel img.main` will fix the issue.

Besides this, your HTML tags aren't properly closed. Below is the corrected HTML.

```
<div class="carousel">
    <img class="main" src="http://www.car-magazine.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Ferrari-Sergio3_4antSX.jpg" />

    <div class="previous"></div>
    <div class="next"></div>

    <div class="thumbnavigator">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://www.ferrariofontario.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/La_Ferrari.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```